# How to create a button for downloading pdf file that is Present in solution explorer?

Tags: c#, html, pdf, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a button in my view page of my ASP.NET CORE.

When user clicks that button a pdf file that is present in the solution(sln)
should download to the user.

```
 I tried a href="location" inside button

 <a href="location" target="blank">download</a>
```

Its not working.

Is there any other way?

Please help me with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using webforms or mvc?

Comment: What exactly did you use as "location", e.g. which filename?

Comment: ASP.NET CORE@GeorgeWurthmann and @Moriarity view page in my mvc filename PDF.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

[Check HTML5 download attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

Just be sure to check the browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the pdf located in your file structure?

Any static files (such as this pdf document) must be located in the wwwroot folder of your dotnet core project.

Additionally, serving of static files must be enabled in your Startup.cs file's Configure method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```